# Trying to generate 11 characted hash String for SMS Retreiver API

Tags: android

I have tried the code from [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify#1_construct_a_verification_message),

```
keytool -exportcert -alias MyAndroidKey -keystore MyProductionKeys.keystore | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n com.example.myapp `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11
```

but got

> 'xxd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

then tried

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin> keytool -exportcert -alias *Alias -keystore *keystorePath | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.exe sha1 -binary | C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl.exe base64
```

Command to get hash string and used the first 11 characted from it inside SMS including <#>.
 But nothing is happening, the broadcast receiver not excecuting onReceive callback. Please help

Comment: can you try google hash calculate example code to find your hash?

Answer (score 1):

You can call this class and it will give you the 11 character hash.

```
public class AppSignatureHelper extends ContextWrapper {
public static final String TAG = AppSignatureHelper.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String HASH_TYPE = "SHA-256";
public static final int NUM_HASHED_BYTES = 9;
public static final int NUM_BASE64_CHAR = 11;

public AppSignatureHelper(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getAppSignatures();
}

/**
 * Get all the app signatures for the current package
 * @return
 */
public ArrayList<String> getAppSignatures() {
    ArrayList<String> appCodes = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // Get all package signatures for the current package
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Signature[] signatures = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;

        // For each signature create a compatible hash
        for (Signature signature : signatures) {
            String hash = hash(packageName, signature.toCharsString());
            if (hash != null) {
                appCodes.add(String.format("%s", hash));
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find package to obtain hash."+ e);
    }
    return appCodes;
}

private static String hash(String packageName, String signature) {
    String appInfo = packageName + " " + signature;
    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_TYPE);
        messageDigest.update(appInfo.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] hashSignature = messageDigest.digest();

        // truncated into NUM_HASHED_BYTES
        hashSignature = Arrays.copyOfRange(hashSignature, 0, NUM_HASHED_BYTES);
        // encode into Base64
        String base64Hash = Base64.encodeToString(hashSignature, Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);
        base64Hash = base64Hash.substring(0, NUM_BASE64_CHAR);

        Log.d(TAG, String.format("pkg: %s -- hash: %s", packageName, base64Hash));
        return base64Hash;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "hash:NoSuchAlgorithm"+ e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}